# Error in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I tried to run db migration and I got the following error

> ```
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authie_sessions" does not exist
> ```
>
> : ALTER TABLE "authie_sessions" ADD "two_factored_at" timestamp/home/levi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:73:in `async_exec'

My migration file is

```
class AddTwoFactorAuthFieldsToAuthie < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    add_column :authie_sessions, :two_factored_at, :datetime
    add_column :authie_sessions, :two_factored_ip, :string
    add_column :authie_sessions, :requests, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :authie_sessions, :password_seen_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

My database.yml is

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: staytus
  host: 127.0.0.1

production:
  <<: *default

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
  database: staytus_test
```

I am using postgresql

Comment: It looks that you don't have `authie_sessions` table, can you check `schema.rb` if it contains such table?

Comment: Actually, it exists in `schema.rb`.



```create_table "authie_sessions", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci" do |t|
    t.string "token"
    t.string "browser_id"
end```

left of some columns due to character length restrictions

Comment: @L11 Check database if there is a table `authie_sessions`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky how can I check that?

Comment: via [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) or any db client like [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `authie_sessions` table exists in both databases `staytus` and `staytus_test`.